How would one define MSCI World Index + 3% or S&P 500 + 3%?
Sometimes private equity-benchmarks contain an illiquidity premium. This is then reflected in something like "MSCI World Index + 3%".
Is there a conventional way of calculating this number for monthly returns? For example, these would be three possibilities:

Monthly benchmark return = MSCI return + 103%^(1/12) - 100%
Monthly benchmark return = MSCI return + 3%/12
Monthly benchmark return = (100% + MSCI return) * 103%^(1/12) - 100%

And I can possibly think of more. Is there some convention?

Have you looked at https://www.gipsstandards.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/guidance-statement-benchmarks-asset-owners.pdf ?

@DimitriVulis Thanks. I've looked at it, and although it is useful, it doesn't address this issue.

I think it addresses it by not addressing it :-) My recollection of GIPS is basically that the asset manager has a fair amount of freedom to choose the details of the benchmark, and that principles of consistency, relevancy, and knowing the benchmark in advance are more important than the small details

(from personal experience I'd expect 2. to be the most common one. 1. might come up occasionally. i would not expect to see 3. this is anecdotal evidence so do with it what you will)

@Rylan Thanks. What I have done is to add the same spread to each month in the same calendar year, such that the calendar year return equals MSCI return + 3%. This means different monthly spreads in different calendar years. (And hope for the best for non-calendar years.) Ugly, but at least the calendar years don't surprise anyone.

I'm surprised, I thought GIPS said something. OK, I googled and found someone's blog entry https://tsgperformance.com/compounding-problems-with-hurdles . I'd still dig deeper into the intent of the current GIPS.

@DimitriVulis Ah. It appears they simply do not compound the hurdle. Which means that the benchmark's monthly returns (including the spread/hurdle) will not geometrically link anymore to form longer periods. That's also possible. But it becomes terribly complicated when the benchmark happens to be a constituent of a composite benchmark.

It's just someone's thoughts in a blog, but I was so sure I remembered something in the 2020 GIPS

OP here. What I have done is to add the same spread to each month in the same calendar year, such that the calendar year return equals MSCI return + 3%. This means different monthly spreads in different calendar years. (And hope for the best for non-calendar years.) Ugly, but at least the calendar years don't surprise anyone.
Edit: One problem: you can't do this midway a current calendar year. (Or every month you'd have to retrospectively change the spreads of the previous months in this calender year.) :(
